# Get error when I install MongoDB on RedHat

Tags: linux, mongodb, installation, redhat, yum

I was trying to install the Mongo Server on my RedHat server via following this document: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-red-hat-centos-or-fedora-linux/

Here is my environment information:

```
[root@localhost tmp]# uname -a
Linux localhost.localdomain 2.6.18-164.el5PAE #1 SMP Tue Aug 18 15:59:11 EDT 2009 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux
[root@localhost yum.repos.d]# ll /etc/yum.repos.d/
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root    115 Apr  3 17:19 10gen.repo
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root   1426 May 24  2009 CentOS-Base.repo
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root    954 Aug 12  2010 epel.repo
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root   1054 Aug 12  2010 epel-testing.repo
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root    684 Jan 18  2007 mirrors-rpmforge
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root   1644 Apr 12  2012 rhel-debuginfo.repo
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root    428 Jan 18  2007 rpmforge.repo
[root@localhost yum.repos.d]# cat 10gen.repo
[10gen]
name=10gen Repository
baseurl=http://downloads-distro.mongodb.org/repo/redhat/os/i686
gpgcheck=0
enabled=1
```

And I get this message when I was trying to install Mongo server:

```
[root@localhost yum.repos.d]# yum install mongo-10gen-server mongo-10gen
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Repository base is listed more than once in the configuration
Repository update is listed more than once in the configuration
Repository addons is listed more than once in the configuration
Repository extras is listed more than once in the configuration
Repository centosplus is listed more than once in the configuration
Repository contrib is listed more than once in the configuration
Repository testing is listed more than once in the configuration
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * epel: mirrors.ustc.edu.cn
 * rpmforge: fr2.rpmfind.net
Setting up Install Process
No package mongo-10gen-server available.
No package mongo-10gen available.
Nothing to do
```

I'm new to Linux, and I'm not quite sure if this was caused by wrong configuration of yum. Can someone help me out of here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I skipped over the Yum problem and I tried to download the package from this website http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-red-hat-centos-or-fedora-linux/ .
It's working.

Answer (score 0):

It's seems you've some conflicts in your config files. Try dowloading the rpm package and installing via rpm -hiv xxx.rpm

Comment: Do you have some shell on this? I'm really new on Linux.

Comment: Scott, you should download the rpm file for you arch then running something like UNIX_PROMPT>sudo rpm -hiv <your_file>
The system will ask you the root password but you should have it since you can run "yum", right? :)

Comment: Hi Dario, yes, you got it! I was trying to install the MongoDB via the document: [link](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-red-hat-centos-or-fedora-linux/), but there's no guide for using rpm command in this webpage. And I now figured out 2 ways to solve it - 1. download the rpm packages and install them via rpm command, but I can't find the packages to download; 2. handle the conflicts in config files, this might be easier and a better solution because I just need to fully re-install Yum (I guess). Can you help me out?

Comment: Actually, I've found the link to download MongoDB, and I have successfully installed it :) However, can you help me to resolve the problem of the conflicts?

Comment: Scott, I'm sorry I've never ran yum in my life.