# yum install mongodb on aws linux fails: no package available

Tags: linux, mongodb, amazon-web-services, yum

**Purpose**

I'm trying to install mongodb on EC2 AWS x86_64 GNU/Linux via Yum.

**Prerequisites**

I created a `/etc/yum.repos.d/mongodb.repo` file and tried all the available combinations for it's content found on the [official documentations](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-amazon/) and on the related questions on stackoverflow [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34725574/yum-install-mongodb-3-2-fails) [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15783870/get-error-when-i-install-mongodb-on-redhat) [link3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40024958/no-package-available-for-mongodb-3-4-community-edition-red-hat-yum-installatio), for example:

```
[mongodb-org-3.4]
name=MongoDB Repository
baseurl=https://repo.mongodb.org/yum/amazon/2013.03/mongodb-org/3.4/x86_64/
gpgcheck=1
enabled=1
gpgkey=https://www.mongodb.org/static/pgp/server-3.4.asc
```

(...tried with enabled=0, gpgcheck=0 too)

I also added a `/etc/yum.conf` file like this:

```
[main]
cachedir=/var/cache/yum/$basearch/$releasever
keepcache=0
debuglevel=2
logfile=/var/log/yum.log
exactarch=1
obsoletes=1
gpgcheck=1
plugins=1
installonly_limit=3
```

**Problem**

I'm getting the same output when running 
`sudo yum install mongodb-org` (or by specifying the packages `sudo yum install mongo-org mongo-org-server` or by specifying the versions too `sudo yum install -y mongodb-org-3.2.13 mongodb-org-server-3.2.13 mongodb-org-shell-3.2.13 mongodb-org-mongos-3.2.13 mongodb-org-tools-3.2.13`)

`Loaded plugins: priorities, update-motd, upgrade-helper
amzn-main                                                | 2.1 kB     00:00
amzn-updates                                             | 2.3 kB     00:00
No package mongodb-org available.
Error: Nothing to do`

**Question**

What am I missing? Is there any additional dependencies?

Answer (score 8):

You don't need to create a new `/etc/yum.repos.d/mongodb.repo` or at the time of this answer `/etc/yum.repos.d/mongodb-org-3.6.repo` cause it already exists but it is empty.

You can check with: `cat /etc/yum.repos.d/mongodb-org-3.6.repo`.

all you need to do is open the file on vi editor:

```
$ sudo vi /etc/yum.repos.d/mongodb-org-3.6.repo
~
~
```

add this code to the repository file. The one i provided is for the  MongoDB 3.6 but you can find the one for earlier versions in the [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-amazon/):

```
[mongodb-org-3.6]
name=MongoDB Repository
baseurl=https://repo.mongodb.org/yum/amazon/2013.03/mongodb-org/3.6/x86_64/
gpgcheck=1
enabled=1
gpgkey=https://www.mongodb.org/static/pgp/server-3.6.asc
```

To save and exit from vi editor check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19911747/working-in-vi-editor-on-ec2-server) or go ahead and do this:

```
ESC + :wq
```

After that you can proceed with the steps in the [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-amazon/) or in the old [C9 Forum](https://community.c9.io/t/setting-up-mongodb/1717), but here they are just in case:

```
$ sudo yum install -y mongodb-org

$ sudo mkdir -p /data/db
$ echo 'mongod --bind_ip=$IP --dbpath=data --nojournal --rest "$@"' > mongod
$ chmod a+x mongod
```

You can start mongodb by running the mongod script on your project root:

```
$ ./mongod
```

The last command might not run the mongodb local server, and you can find the solution for that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6478113/unable-to-start-mongodb-local-server) or just go ahead and run these two commands:

```
$ sudo service mongod stop
$ sudo mongod
```

Answer (score 1):

The only error I can spot is the space in "name" :

> name=MongoDB Repository

With the naming changed to name=MongoDB, I did a test with CenOS 7 :

```
# yum search mongodb-org
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks
base                                      | 3.6 kB     00:00            
.      
mongodb-org-3.4                           | 2.5 kB     00:00     
updates                                   | 3.4 kB     00:00     
(1/5): mongodb-org-3.4/primary_db         |  30 kB   00:00     
.
=========================== N/S matched: mongodb-org ============
mongodb-org-debuginfo.x86_64 : Debug information for package mongodb-org
mongodb-org.x86_64 : MongoDB open source document-oriented database system
                   : (metapackage)
mongodb-org-mongos.x86_64 : MongoDB sharded cluster query router
mongodb-org-server.x86_64 : MongoDB database server
mongodb-org-shell.x86_64 : MongoDB shell client
mongodb-org-tools.x86_64 : MongoDB tools
```

So I guess you can now install ``mongodb-org´´.

Comment: thank you @knud-larsen, good catch, but made no difference for me, still getting the `No package mongodb-org available. Error: Nothing to do`

Comment: It's a don't know. ... I also tried using your `yum.conf` . No issues.  `yum search mongodb-org` is OK, all packages are avuilable.

Answer (score 1):

There is a dedicated repository for AWS Linux now.
Follow the instructions from https://docs.mongodb.com/master/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-amazon/
e.g.

```
[mongodb-org-4.4]
name=MongoDB Repository
baseurl=https://repo.mongodb.org/yum/amazon/2/mongodb-org/4.4/x86_64/
gpgcheck=1
enabled=1
gpgkey=https://www.mongodb.org/static/pgp/server-4.4.asc
```

Comment: 2023 Review: You are right it is compatible with Amazon Linux 2

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I wanted to do it from the default ec2_user/ home folder. You need to cd .. up to the root, and locate the etc/yum.repos.d/ folder there.

Answer (score 0):

For those of you finding this error after running an ARM AMI Linux 2 image, simply install the RPMs directly from the testing repository, which is the only one that supports all binaries on Amazon AArch64:

https://repo.mongodb.org/yum/amazon/2/mongodb-org/testing/aarch64/RPMS/

For example, to install the latest mongo shell:

```
sudo yum install -y https://repo.mongodb.org/yum/amazon/2/mongodb-org/testing/aarch64/RPMS/mongodb-org-shell-4.4.4-0.1.rc1.amzn2.aarch64.rpm
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this happen when my install commands specified `sudo yum install mongodb-org-tools-4.0.18`, but `yum list available | grep mongo` showed only 3.6 was available. So I did `sudo yum install mongodb-org-tools` and that worked.

Answer (score -1):

I think you try to add `exclude` directory from `/etc/yum.conf` to prevent future updates
for example:

```
exclude=mongodb-org,mongodb-org-server,mongodb-org-shell,mongodb-org-mongos,mongodb-org-tools
```

But above line need to be added after perform install mongodb-org:

```
sudo yum install -y mongodb-org
```